# Microsoft Bing v7 search parameters not functioning

Tags: bing-api

I am trying out MS Bing v7 API.

If I enter a curl request:

```
curl -H "Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key:<MYKEY>" https://api.bing.microsoft.com/v7.0/search?q=vintage+cars&count=25&responseFilter=webpages,news,-images,-videos
```

I do not get 25 results, only `#WebPages.0` to `#WebPages.9` are returned.  If, as seems to be suggested, I should use the `offset` parameter (eg: &offset=0) in the above curl request, then (JSON) references to images and videos are returned (despite the -images,-videos) along with a web page count again of only 10.  The same happens in Java code.

I realise the MS documentation is not up to date.  There are, for example, references to WebPage (and other entities) with fields missing in the documentation (eg: richFacts in WebPage).

So have the count/offset/responseFilter parameters been changed or been updated or am I just using them wrong somehow?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is two things:

1. Despite the documentation stating -videos,-images etc. is valid, they are not. Just use Webpages,News.
2. The https://... string (in cURL) needs to be embedded in quotes.